# get state from another component react

Tags: reactjs

how i get state idf from component Home? i want to get state idf from home.js to detail.js.

my Home.js

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(){

    super();
    this.state = {
      dataOperations: [],
      distributorOperations: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  idFor(e) {
    this.state = {
      idf: e
    };
   window.location = "#/detail";
  }
```

I want to get the state idf in here detail.js. this is not his children

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SingleProduct from '../assets/Singleproduct'
import ListProductHorizontal from '../assets/ListProducthorizontal'
import LoaderPage from '../assets/LoaderComponent'
import Home from './Home'
import Axios from 'axios'

class DetailProduct extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          dataOperations: [],
        isLoading: true
        };
      console.log(this.state.idf)
```

Comment: Can you pass the value using props ? Or have you had a look at redux ?

Comment: value of e is number

Comment: state is private to a class component and you won't be able to use it in another component. If the components share a parent child relationship, you could lift the state up or think about using redux

Comment: You should use something like React-router for navigation.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do `this.state = { .. }` from anywhere other than a constructor. You might need to change it to `this.setState`.

Comment: Only medium to pass data between child and parent is by using props unless you use Redux. So you should use props to pass specific data. This state is limited to respective component so hence it will not help in propagating the data forward. So you should probably use props in these conditions where data is to be exposed to outer world. Hope you get it cleared